# Imbed YouTube in PPT with multiple start and end times

Tags: powerpoint

Is there a way to imbed a YouTube video in Powerpoint so it plays multiple non-consecutive segments?
For example, if I wanted it to play from 00:00 to 6:13, then jump to 11:15 and play until 15:04, then jump to 20:25 and play to the end, is there a way to include that in the imbed code?

Or, do I just have to imbed the video multiple times with different Start & End times?